# Remover parte do intervalo de tempo Kendo TimePicker

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, telerik

Ao utilizar `TimePicker` do `KendoUI` para definir uma seleção de horário de atendimento, foi definido o período minimo (8h00) e máximo (18:00), porém será necessário remover o intervalo de 12h00 até 13h30 desta lista.

Como realizar está ação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer isso você deverá utilizar configuration dates. 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/timepicker#configuration-dates

Veja o exemplo abaixo.
Obs.: Esquente com a data não. Apenas com as horas.

```
$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
dates: [
    new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0),
    new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 30, 0),
    new Date(2000, 10, 10, 11, 0, 0),

    new Date(2000, 10, 10, 15, 0, 0),
    new Date(2000, 10, 10, 15, 30, 0),
    new Date(2000, 10, 10, 16, 0, 0)
] //vai mostra 10:00 AM até 11:00 AM e 3:00 PM até 4:00 PM
```

});